# Cannot install a whl library

Tags: python, installation, pip

When i try to install this OpenCV file the cmd give me an error. I'm new in python and I'm doing a school job, can someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `pip` from a python terminal, but from your system terminal/command line interface.